# Selenium Setting value with JavaScriptExecutor, value flips back

Tags: c#, angular, selenium

I have this element which I cannot use SendKeys on.  No idea why, but SendKeys does not change the value.

```
<input class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="hour" matinput="" maxlength="2" type="text" id="mat-input-70" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
```

So I tried using JavaScriptExecutor  (this is C#)

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)SeleniumWebDriverManager.GetSeleniumWebDriver().WebDriver;
js.ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].value='{text}';", this.rootElement);
```

I can see the value change in the page, but a couple seconds later, it flips back to the original.

Does anyone know why or what I can do to change this value?

Comment: How is `this.rootElement` defined?

Comment: Can you share a link to the page? Setting values using JS is almost always a bad idea because you are going around the UI/design and it can cause problems.

Comment: this.rootElement is a SeleniumWebElement  (in this case, the input one shown above).  I cannot share the page because it's internal.  I completely agree that JS is a bad idea, but I cannot for some reason use SendKeys on this element.  I'm not sure what's different between this element and the thousands of others that SendKeys has worked for!!  :-)

Comment: Most likely there is JavaScript executing on the page that resets the value. It is also probably preventing you from using `SendKeys` too.